# Is it faster to clearRect() the whole canvas or to clearRect() only some piece?

Tags: html5-canvas

I benchmarked clearRect() to clear the whole canvas:

`clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)`

vs clearRect() of the small area that I need cleared only.

1. I tried for both small (800x500) and big (1000x3000) canvases.
2. I turned off the reduced time precision in Firefox when testing.
3. I turned off all privacy addons that wrap canvas method to avoid exploitation through canvas.
4. I measured start_time and end_time with using `performance.now()` (and not Date.now()).

No matter what I do, it seems like `clearRect()` performance is totally unpredictable and incomparable. Sometimes clearing the whole canvas is faster, sometimes it is slower; in both cases up to 2x faster or slower. It's totally random.

Can someone elaborate what the browser is doing and why the results are so different and incomparable?

And as importantly, what is expected to work faster?

Answer (score 1):

`clearRect()` is actually a `fillRect()` with a `"clear"` composite mode.
In most engines this operation will be done by the GPU, like any paint and the size of the cleared area matters very little.
What may matter is the composition with the remaining pixels (antialiasing).
What will matter is the number of operations.

So if you really have only one single part to clear, clearing only this part may be similar or better than clearing the whole (depending on what needs to be redrawn), but as soon as you have multiple parts to clear, then clearing the whole should be faster.

All this being said, the most important point to consider is the readability of your code, and it can be noted that the "clear-all,redraw-all" strategy is the de-facto standard among canvas programmers.

Comment: Thanks. I don’t care about the readability of the code at all, I just need it fast.

Comment: Then benchmark. Without seeing what you are doing we can't tell which will be faster. But while I don't want to sound patronizing, from my own experience after few years in this area, not a single time I chose clearing only a part of the canvas over clearing it all.

Comment: Benchmarked. Performance of clearRect() and fillRect() is hugely inconsistent depending on the browser and iOS. There are also some issues reported in FF, Safari and Chrome re performance of those functions, as well as drawImage(). So it turns out there is no definitive answer nor a solution to provide some consistent performance, no matter what function I use.

Answer (score -1):

It is faster to just clear the area of the screen that needs to be cleared.

for example

```
clearRect(camera.x,camera.y,camera.width,camera.height);
```

Clearing less is more efficient than clearing more.

Comment: “It is expected” explains nothing. Please elaborate.